# Why isn't JavaScript running when I refernce the external file in between the head tags in my html file?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When I put the link to my JS file in between my html header tags the js file will not run. However if I put the external js link after my body tag or somewhere after the bulk of my html code the file runs. Is there any way to make the external js file run when I link the external file in between the head tags. I also should mention that I'm doing HTML DOM in the external js file.

HTML Portion:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>HTMLDOM Practice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HTMLDOM Practice.css"/>
    <!--I would like to put external js file here-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
        <p id="txt">Hello World!</p>
    </div>
</body>
    <script src="HTMLDOM Practice.js"></script>
</html>
```

Javascript/HTML DOM portion:

```
var x = document.getElementById('txt'); 
var b = document.getElementById('box');

x.addEventListener('click',irt,false);
b.addEventListener('click',irt,false);

function irt(){
    x.innerHTML="Goodbye world!";
    b.style.padding="20px"; 
}
```

Comment: The script is trying to grab elements that dont exist. Ur txt and box elements dont get declared until after the script runs, so the script errors out.

Comment: How would you fix this, because didn't I already declare my two html elements as var x and var b in js?

Comment: I found the missing line of code that should make it work. I remember watching a tutorial on YouTube and forgot you needed this line of code **window.addEventListener('load', myFunction, false);** to initialize the elements so the script can grab them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i know it can be annoying to place JS code at the bottom of the page just to use DOM. As a good practise I usually load the JS in the head.

You could workaround something like this.
1) Place a function in your JS file which does the initialising
2) Call the initialise function OnLoad.

JS FILE looks like this

```
var x;
var b;

function irt(){
    x.innerHTML="Goodbye world!";
    b.style.padding="20px"; 
} 

function setEverything(){
    x = document.getElementById('txt'); 
    b = document.getElementById('box');

    x.addEventListener('click',irt,false);
    b.addEventListener('click',irt,false);
}
```

HTML body tag

```
<body onload="setEverything()">
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem as I see it is that the JS is running before the DOM has finished loading. To fix this, simply add `defer` to your `script` tag which will defer the execution of the JS until everything else has completed:

`<script src="HTMLDOM Practice.js" defer></script>`

Furthermore, if the browser supports it, you can opt for asynchronous download and execution of the JS files by using `async`. You can combine this with `defer` for best results across differing browsers:

`<script src="HTMLDOM Practice.js" async defer></script>`